# Pusher in laravel 5.4 not receiving

Tags: laravel, pusher

In my app.js file I have:

```
Echo.channel('channel-name').listen('Event', (e) => {console.log(e)});
```

everytime I push to pusher, I get the API MESSAGE, but the console.log is not working at all. I noticed that I can press the refresh button next to the API MESSAGE button on pusher's debug console I can get the console.log...

Is there anything else that I forget to configure or setup?

Comment: Can we see your instantiation of `window.Echo = `

Comment: I just switched to chrome and did the test, the code is actually working. I get my console.log. I have been using firefox all the time. Still want to know why it doen't work on firefox. I aslo uninstall all plug-ins on firefox. it didn't work.